# Webkit browser & automation

Tags: testing, browser, webkit, automation

Have anyone come across open source tools/framework for Webkit browser test automation?

Answer (score 1):

There is (not tried) [WebAii Automation Framework](http://www.artoftest.com/products/webaii.aspx) where the [current Beta 2.0.0.1](http://www.artoftest.com/community/blogs/09-03-25/WebAii_2_0_Beta_Released.aspx) has Safari 3 support added on windows (it's free but I don't think it's opensource).

If you want do it yourself:

On Apple you should be able to script it AppleScript or from

MAC OS X > 10.4: there is [**Automator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software))

On Windows you might consider using [**P/Invoke**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx) and looking at the [WinLauncher](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebKitTools/WinLauncher) tool from WebKitTools

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a framework to run the tests but if you're looking for input to test against there is Ian Hickson's [adhoc](http://hixie.ch/tests/adhoc/) and [evil](http://hixie.ch/tests/evil/) test suites in addition to the traditional [acid tests](http://www.acidtests.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Which WebKit? Selenium seems to have drivers for several WebKit-based browsers.

WebKit itself has a test suite, to be implemented by each platform, which the WebKit documentation calls [DRT or DumpRenderTree](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Writing%20Layout%20Tests%20for%20DumpRenderTree) (see also LayoutTestController).